# Hi i have a programming project and I'm getting wierd errors when compiling the program

Tags: c++, cin

I have to create a calculator where a user decides what operator to use. The code I have currently is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    char 'op'[5];
    cout << "Enter first integer" << endl;
    cin >> i;
    cout << "Enter second integer" << endl;
    cin >> j;
    cout << "Select the operator" << endl;
    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
        i + j = k;
        cout << k << endl;
        break;
        case '-':
        i - j = k;
        cout << k << endl;
        break;
        case '*':
        i * j = k;
        cout << k << endl;
        break;
        case '/':
        i/j = k;
        cout << k << endl;
        break;
        default:
        cout << "Please enter a valid operator" << endl;
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In c++ is it not allowed for a user to cin an operator? IF it is I can just create another switch case.

Comment: That's quite a declaration `char 'op'[5]`. I don't really know what that means.  To declare an object/array in this case, you need `char op[5]`. You've defined a char string array of nothing, I think.  That's pretty much it.  `cin` you'll have to hit RETURN also. It's not a simple key stroke.  Note: You'll also be comparing a string/array to a character in the switch statement.  You can do a simple hack and use `switch (op[0])` or use `std::string`

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm still a little confused as I was taught that char values were defined inside single quotes? Under what circumstances would I include the single quotes?

Comment: Use single quotes to assign a character value to a variable like this: `char mychar = '+';`

Comment: For future reference: "I'm getting wierd errors" is not a problem description. You have the compiler errors right in front of you. There's no reason not to include them in your question. The error messages also contain the specific line number where the error is happening. It's a good idea to provide the information you already have; remember, you're asking us to help you solve *your problem* for free, so making it as easy for us as possible is always the best idea. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are not reading `op`. You still need to do something like `cin >> op;` before the `switch()` statement.

Also, assigning values always works from right to left. You can not do `i + j = k;`

It has to be `k = i + j;`

Comment: Also, `char 'op'[5];` is not a valid declaration. Use `char op[5];` instead. But since you are only interested in a single `char` value, drop the array syntax altogether: `char op;`

Comment: In that case, under what situations would i include the single quotes?

Comment: Never. Names of variables are never quoted.